# Gulp task, add const to task-line

Tags: gulp, task, constants

I wonder if there is a way to call some tasks in the same one but previously declared in a const. I tried to do this but is not working correctly:

```
// Tasks initialization
const INIT = ['tree', 'media', 'concat']
    DEV = ['uglify', 'xml', 'watch']
    RELEASE = ['thumbnails', 'zip'];

gulp.task('init', INIT)
gulp.task('default', INIT && DEV)
gulp.task('release', INIT && DEV && RELEASE)
```

gulp is running but some tasks are not. If I put them separately works fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a basic solution using IE6

```
const INIT = ['tree', 'media', 'concat']
DEV = ['tree', 'media', 'concat', 'uglify', 'xml', 'watch']
RELEASE = ['thumbnails'];

gulp.task('init', INIT)
gulp.task('default', [...INIT, ...DEV])
gulp.task('release', [...INIT, ...DEV, ...RELEASE])
```

Comment: or INIT.concat(DEV) and INIT.concat(DEV).concat(RELEASE).  The && is a logical operator which returns true/false not the combination of two arrays.